# Chemfig and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, chemfig

How can I make a chemical graph, with empty boxes, like this:
[image]
In chemfig + TikZ? Or there is some other way?
Somebody try something like this before?

Comment: Did you try something? Do you want to use `chemfig` for other diagrams in your document? Because then, you might want to use it here as well ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to draw this. You could use the `chemfig` package like in the following exammple, but you could also directly use Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\setchemfig{arrow coeff=2}
\newcommand{\chembox}{\tikz{\draw[rounded corners=2pt] (0,0) rectangle (2,.5);}}
\schemestart
    \chemfig{CH_4}
    \arrow{->[\chembox][1.]}
    \chembox
    \arrow{->[\chemfig{Na}][2.]}
    \chembox
    \arrow{->[\parbox{7em}{\centering 
        1) \chemfig{Cl_2}, hv \\ 
        2) \chemfig{OH^{-}}, alk, $\Delta$
    }][3.]}
    \chembox
\schemestop


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility.

It is possible to insert more complex molecules with ChemFig.

There is no need to create new commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document} 
\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_4}
\arrow{->[\begin{tcolorbox}[width=2cm,colframe=blue,colback=white]
        \ce{S2O^{2-}_{3}}
    \end{tcolorbox}][1]}[,2]
\chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-}
\arrow{->[\begin{tcolorbox}[width=1.5cm,colframe=blue,colback=white]
        \chemfig{[,.2]**6(------)}
    \end{tcolorbox}][2]}[,2]
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]